# form action not mapping controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

form action is not mapping to the controller.

my signup.html

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/signup}" th:object="${memberDto}">

<input type="submit" value="Sign up">
```

my MemberController.java

```
@Controller
public class MemberController {
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String register(Model model){
        System.out.println("-----getmapping-----");
        model.addAttribute("memberDto",new MemberDto());
        return "view/signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("memberDto") MemberDto memberDto, BindingResult bindingResult){
        System.out.println("-----postmapping-----");
        return "view/signup";
    }
}
```

Getmapping works well, but form action (Postmapping) is not working...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any error? Please tell exactly what is happening. Check the response code returned by server using any developer tool in browser. Is the request sent by browser?

Comment: Even if you press 'submit', '@RequestMapping' of the controller does not work, and it goes to /.

Comment: Nothing wrong in this code except ```form``` tag is not closed. You need to add more code.

Comment: This is for testing if it works: Try to remove annotation @Valid from your method parameters, then replace MemberDto with ModelMap. And see if it works. Try to debug the code. Then when you see what is wrong, fix it by applying it to the code that you have written.

Comment: After removing @Valid, it works normally. Thank you all!!!